# Is there a way to bulk export actions into separate GLB with script?

Tags: python, export, gltf

```
import os

# Get the directory path of the Blender file
filepath = bpy.data.filepath
directory = os.path.dirname(filepath)

# Create the export directory if it doesn't exist
export_directory = os.path.join(directory, "export")
os.makedirs(export_directory, exist_ok=True)

for action in bpy.data.actions:
    # Set the active action
    bpy.context.object.animation_data.action = action

    # Get the action name without spaces
    action_name = action.name.replace(" ", "_")

    # Set the export filepath for the current action
    export_filepath = os.path.join(export_directory, f"{action_name}.glb")

    bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(
        filepath=export_filepath,
        export_format="GLB",
        export_animations=True,
        use_visible=True,
        export_materials="EXPORT",
        export_extras=True,
        export_apply=True,
    )
```

So I have been trying to modify the code to do it. But have no luck. If anyone knows if it is possible to achieve this?

I have 100 actions in my blender file. I want to export those actions into 100glb with the action name for the glb filename...

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you run this code? "But have no luck." is not a good error description. The script exports all actions when i add `import bpy` at the beginning of the file.